# Miktex unable to install due to dependencies (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, latex

I can't install MikTex. The miktex site suggest that Ubuntu 20.04 is supported, but upon installing I get:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
> miktex : Depends: libboost-locale1.65.1 but it is not installable
> Depends: libhunspell-1.6-0 but it is not installable
> Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.